# How to use one website with several amazon S3 buckets as a path suffixes?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to host multiple S3 Amazon buckets under one site in next way: Access to bucket1 - http://example.com/bucket1(bucket2...) and so on. What now Amazon allows is access with links like http://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucket1 , but this is not allowed in my case (production server). Note that site DNS is hosted also at Amazon Route53.

Comment: You'd have to proxy it. Are you sure this is useful enough to justify the work, additional bandwidth usage, and extra latency it'll involve?

Comment: Would you be comfortable with a pattern like: [http://bucket1.example.com](http://bucket1.example.com) where bucket1 is now a subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I can think of is to route to your buckets using subdomains:  http://bucket1.example.com ,  [http://bucket2.example.com](http://bucket1.example.com)

All you would need to do is to create the relevant subdomain in your Route 53 configuration, and then alias it by creating a CNAME record.
So, `bucketn.example.com` will have a CNAME record with `bucketn.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com`.

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html) reference from AWS may help.